# Connecting SQL Anywhere with Sybase database file on local computer

Tags: sybase-sql-anywhere

I have installed SQL Anywhere 12 in my system.

I have a `.db` file in my computer. I have no idea what is it's username and password.

If I try to connect to it by providing credentials- username=DBA and password=sql
I'm getting below error-

[image]

How can I connect to it successfully?

Comment: Maybe the transcript shown is misleading but if I were to interpret it, I'd have concluded that you've just got no database server running on your computer at all. And I can't imagine how you can access a database file without a server instance – which currently running software would be processing it?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to reset the password using the free SQL Anywhere 17 Developer edition. The paid edition should work also.

```
"C:\Program Files\SQL Anywhere 17\bin64\dbsrv17.exe"  dbsrv17 -orp "UID=DBA;NEWPWD=newpassword;AUTHUID=reset_user;AUTHPWD=sql456" C:\database.file.db
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no known way to get access to a sql anywhere database when you have lost the password.

Here a list of other such articles:

- http://sqlanywhere-forum.sap.com/questions/14025/password-dba
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21101024/sybase-database-password-recovery
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/731142/password-recovery-for-sybase-file
- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sybase.public.sqlanywhere.general/1ohYauJnfnw

Your best hope will be to contact the sql anywhere supprt (SAP now) and prove ownership of the database and they perhaps can reset the password